# Minecraft webpage links in chat?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I have seen links in servers that can send you to a page in a browser, is there any way to replicate this with command blocks?

I don't mean command links, I mean web pages.

Comment: So like, if a command block is powered -> open webpage?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The [`/tellraw` command](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Commands#tellraw) allows you to output to chat with more formatting options than `/say`. You'll need to use this, and the JSON format that it uses, to add clickable links to chat.

[Here's a guide to the format tellraw (and signs, books and titles) use, if you are not already familiar with it.](http://www.minecraftforum.net/forums/minecraft-discussion/redstone-discussion-and/351959-1-9-json-text-component-for-tellraw-title-books)

Links can be added using the `open_url` click event. Example:

```
/tellraw @p {"text":"Arqade","clickEvent":{"action":"open_url","value":"http://gaming.stackexchange.com"}}
```

[Here's a tellraw generator that allows you to add `open_url` click events](https://www.minecraftjson.com), which is usually easier than writing it manually.